# Functional dependencies implied by other functional dependencies

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

Consider the follow attributes and functional dependencies

Attributes: A, B, C, D, E, F, H

Functional Dependencies:

A→ D

AE → H

DF → B, C

E → C

H → E

Which of the following dependencies is implied by above dependencies?

A) A → DH

B) AED →C

C) DH → C

D) ADF → E

The answer for this question is B. Can anyone help me explain how it got to B, I have looked at the transitive dependencies but non would imply that

Comment: Hi. Please google 'stackexchange homework'. What is your textbook? What does it say about FDs "implied by"? What do you get applying that? [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to answer to this kind of question is to compute for each functional dependency the closure of the determinant with respect to the given functional dependencies and see if the determinate belongs to such closure.

For instance, we can compute the closure of A, A+, to see if A → DH is implied:

```
A+ = A
A+ = AD (because of A → D)
stop, no other attribute can be added to the closure.
```

So, since DH is not contained in A+, we can conclude that  A → DH is not implied.

Let's use the same method for AED → C:

```
AED+ = AED
AED+ = AEDH (for AE → H)
AED+ = ACDEH (for A → C)
```

No other dependencies can be used, so the final closure is: ACDEH, which contains C, so that AED → C is implied.

If you apply this method, you could discover that also DH → C is implied by the given functional dependencies.

Comment: It would be clearer if the first sentence said "each FD" *in the proposed solutions*. (Although one can figure that out from what follows.) Also it says "see if the determinate belongs to such closure", but you don't explain what "see if" means. Also you don't actually *give* "the" "method" behind your "since" (associated with the "see if"), you just apply it without giving it. (And why it works.) PS This question shows zero effort and is too broad and is a duplicate, it should be downvoted & close voted.